# Dynamically Filled Navigation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I have a responsive navigation with a number of links in.

Historically, we have set width on each of `<li>`'s individually.

However, I'd like to space the links on the navigation out filling the entire width of the containing `<ul>` evenly.

Is there a nice way to do this, preferably not using Javascript.

Comment: is this what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Q68jy/

Comment: You could use flexbox [w3 docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css-flexbox-1-20140325/) the [support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) is getting there, and a [guide](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simplest ways is to use a table-cell layout...no, not an actual table but...

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/Q68jy/7/)

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul{
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}
li{
    display: table-cell;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid grey; /* visual reference only */
    background:#bada55; /* visual reference only */
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a table? is it just because `<ul>`'s are shorter to write?

Comment: Arguably no  but in general it's recommended that tables are for **actual tabular data** not basic layout. What we have here doesn't meet that criteria but we can use CSS 'table-like' properties to fake it.